# Invalid bind expression type of String for column of type Decimal. Auto type casting?

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql, sosl

I ran into this exception while trying to make some dynamic SOQL queries(also SOSL but haven't gotten to test those yet).

Basically I'm trying to build a query string and add a dynamic value as one of the parameters. Problem is I don't know what type that value will be(string, integer, etc). I don't think I can manually cast to all possible types, I'm looking for a more elegant solution.
Code in question:

```
qryHolder = 'SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE {0} =: val';
```

Where `val` is `String val = String.valueOf(sobj.get(fieldName.getName()));` `sobj` is a random sobject, `fieldName` is `Schema.DesribeFieldResult`.
I can also make something like

```
'SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE {0} = {2}'
```

And {2} would be val but then it doesn't work for Strings and only work for Numbers.
Any solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind to an Object.

Then you can set values which will work for a number field:

```
Object val = 42;
```

Or a text field:

```
Object val = 'Some text';
```

And so on.

Comment: Yup - tested it after posting and wanted to come here to post the answer. You beat me to it. :)